# how to do a word count from getline?

Tags: c, pointers

So i am trying to get the word count from the getline function, but i keep getting a segmentation fault error.  Here, you can assume that white space will only be defined as '\t', '\n', and ' '.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int tokenCount(char *mystring){
    int word=0;
    char *ptr = mystring;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<strlen(mystring);i++){

            if(ptr[i]!=' ' || ptr[i]!= '\t' || ptr[i]!='\n'){
                    word++;

                    while(ptr[i]!= ' ' || ptr[i]!= '\t' || ptr[i] != '\n'){

                      i++;
                    }
            }

    }


return word;
}

int main (){

    size_t n = 10;
    char *mystring = malloc(10);

    if(mystring==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "No memory\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    while(getline(&mystring, &n, stdin)>0){


            printf("%d\n", tokenCount(mystring));
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(ptr[i]!= ' ' || ptr[i]!= '\t' || ptr[i] != '\n'){
```

So, in English, while the value at `i` is *not* a space character, ***or*** the value at `i` is *not* a tab character, ***or*** the value at `i` is *not* a newline. See the problem? If `ptr[i]` is `'a'`, then it passes this test because it's not a space (good). But if it's as `' '` (space char), it still passes, because while it's equal to `' '`, it's not equal to `'\t'`, so the loop continues (bad). This is an infinite loop, and since it increments `i`, you run off the end of the array the pointer references into unallocated memory and crash.

Fix the test to use `&&`, not `||`, and make sure you haven't reached the end of the string before performing it (also, cache the `strlen` at the beginning, don't recompute over and over):

```
size_t mystringlen = strlen(mystring);

...

if (ptr[i]!= ' ' && ptr[i]!= '\t' && ptr[i] != '\n') {
    ++word;
    while(i < mystringlen && ptr[i]!= ' ' && ptr[i]!= '\t' && ptr[i] != '\n'){

...
```

With a slight logic change (catches more whitespace characters) this could be simplified with [`isspace`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace):

```
if (!isspace(ptr[i])) {
    ++word;
    while(i < mystringlen && !isspace(ptr[i])){
```

Comment: <joke>don't say crash, the correct way is <strong>undefined behaviour</strong></joke>